# Sorting Linked list of objects with respect to values

Tags: java, linked-list

I have a custom class as follows.

```
class customclass {

int a;
int b;
}
```

I have put objects of this class in a linked list.

```
LinkedList<customclass> ll = new LinkedList<customclass>();
customclass c1= new customclass();
c1.a=1;
c1.b=5;
ll.add(c1);
customclass c2= new customclass();
c2.a=10;
c2.b=5;
ll.add(c2);
customclass c3= new customclass();
c2.a=11;
c2.b=15;
ll.add(c3);
```

How to use Collections.sort to sort the list with respect to values of "a" from each object of the class customclass.

Comment: Write a Comparator for your class and pass it as a parameter to the sort() method.  It's right there in the javadocs.

Comment: Please adhere to Java naming conventions. Classes should be in `PascalCase`, `camelCase` is reserved for variables. Failing to do so makes your code much harder for us to read and also breaks SO's syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Collections.sort(l1, new Comparator<customclas>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(customclas o1, customclas o2) {
                if (o1.a < o2.a) return -1;
                else if (o1.a > o2.a) return 1;
                else return 0;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

First, please name your class correctly.

Second, please use proper encapsulation.

So we have:

```
class Customclass {

    private final int a;
    private final int b;

    public Customclass(int a, int b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public int getB() {
        return b;
    }

}
```

Now to sort we just do:

```
final List<Customclass> ll = new LinkedList<>();
Collections.sort(ll, Comparator.comparing(Customclass::getA));
```

Notice that I use diamond notation, `<>`, to avoid declaring the type of the `List` twice and also I use the interface, `List`, rather than the implementation, `LinkedList`, on the LHS.

Comment: +1, for the general advice... and because I love Java8's feature :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Comparator<customclass> comparator = new Comparator<customclass>() {
    public int compare(customclass c1,customclass c2) {
        //return c2.a - c1.a; 
        // use your logic
        // updating as per borris
        Integer.compare(c1.a,c2.a);
    }
};

Collections.sort(ll, comparator);
```

Comment: @BoristheSpider actually there was no criteria on the question how the objects will be sorted depending on the value of customclass.a

Comment: The hack (`inta - intb`) is never a valid way of sorting integers. The fact that the OP provided no critera does not mean that you should post a subtly broken approach.